# Node JS Express update issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

i'm having problem implementing an update within my express application.
http://localhost:3000/update2?buyerID=2299
when i enter the link shown above it takes me to a form but its empty...
I want this form to be populated with the current values related to buyer ID document.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

**json file**

http://prntscr.com/dil1fj

**js file**

```
router.get('/update2', function(req, res) {
    var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;

    if (!buyerID || !parseInt(buyerID)) {
        res.render('error', {message: "You need to enter an ID to update a specific order", error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
    } else {

        mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect to MongoDB",error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
            } else {
                var WishList = db.collection('orders');
                WishList.findOne({"buyerID": parseInt(buyerID)}, function(err, result) {
                    if (err || !result || result.length == 0) {
                        res.render('error', {message: "Failed to find order",error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
                    } else {
                        res.render('updateOrder2', {updateOrder2: result, qs: req.query});
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
});

router.post('/update2', function(req, res) {
    var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;

    if (!buyerID || !parseInt(buyerID)) {
        res.render('error', {message: "Failed to update order make sure the ID is current", error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
    } else {

        mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect to MongoDB", error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
            } else {
                var WishList = db.collection('orders');

                var order = {
                    buyerID: req.body.buyerID,
                    gender: req.body.gender,
                    student: req.body.student,
                    pName: req.body.pName,
                    type: req.body.type,
                    purchaseDate: req.body.purchaseDate,
                    price: req.body.price,
                    sName: req.body.sName

                };
                console.log("Updating..", order)
                WishList.updateOne({"buyerID": parseInt(buyerID)}, {$set: order}, function (err, result){
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Cannot update", err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("Updated..", order)
                        res.redirect("/orders")
                    }
                })

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**updateOrder2.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Recipe</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>

<form name= "updateOrder" action="/updateOrder" method="POST">
    User ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="buyerID" value = <%=qs.buyerID%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender" value = <%=qs.gender%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Student?:<br>
    <input type="text" name="student" value = <%=qs.student%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Product ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="productID" value = <%=qs.productID%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Product Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="pName" value = <%=qs.pName%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Product Type:<br>
    <input type="text" name="type" value = <%=qs.type%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Date Purchased:<br>
    <input type="text" name="purchaseDate" value = <%=qs.purchaseDate%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Product Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="price" value = <%=qs.price%>/ required ="required"><br>
    Seller Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="sName" value = <%=qs.sName%>/ required ="required"><br>
    <br><br>



    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you see when you look at the empty form's source code in your browser? Are you getting any errors in the node console?

Comment: im getting no errors, i just want the the fields to populate in the form with the data relating to that buyerID

Comment: I've never used ejs, but I'm pretty sure you a) need to at put at least values that contain spaces in quotes and b) remove the slashes. Also, What do you see as source code? Does it contain "value ="? If so, what is inserted after that? Also, you're passing `qs: req.query` to the renderer. Shouldn't you pass `qs: result`?

Comment: the qs:result loaded the data into the form! That part works now :D lets see if it actually updates it

Comment: it doesnt seem to be updating the documents with the fields i passed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used ejs, but I'm pretty sure you a) need to at put at least values that contain spaces in quotes and b) remove the slashes. Also, What do you see as source code? Does it contain "value ="? If so, what is inserted after that? Also, you're passing `qs: req.query` to the renderer. Shouldn't you pass `qs: result`?

Regarding the update, I'm guessing this `var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;` at the start of `router.post('/update2'` is the problem; you need to use `req.body.buyerID`. I recommend adding lots of `console.log()` commands to your code at crucial lines.

Comment: if u can look at my latest problem please, i can figure this one out too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this var buyerID = req.query.buyerID; at the start of router.post('/update2' is the problem; you need to use req.body.buyerID. I recommend adding lots of console.log() commands to your code at crucial lines. – Chris G 4 mins ago